# Siebel createFile method

Tags: javascript, jquery, siebel

Siebel provides "CreateFile" business Method to create a file in the Siebel file system from an external source.

The Syntax of the API is as below:

```
BusComp.InvokeMethod("CreateFile", SrcFilePath, KeyFieldName, KeepLink)
```

SrcFilePath: The fully qualified path of the file on  Web Client.

Our idea was user will choose the file by HTML input file component and we will pass file to Siebel createFile business method.

Unfortunately modern browsers are not giving absolute path of the file chosen by HTML input file component.

Is there any way:

1) To pass JavaScript File object to Siebel CreateFile  function 
or 
2) To get absolute file path in JavaScript from HTML Input File

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: For security reasons, browser's don't send the client file full path.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am aware of that.

Comment: Check [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp). It does this `var x = document.getElementById("myFile").value;`. Which brings the full path on older browsers but a "C:\fakepath" on newer ones. If you can control which browser to use, this will do the trick. I tried it on IE 6 and 7.

Comment: Thanks, Only legacy IE (6.x) will give the path of the file.  As you mention, modern browser that too FireFox and Chrome will give fake path.  But what we need is the actual file path of the chosen file.

Comment: If you can't control which browser users should use (or if downgrading to IE 7 isn't an option), you'll have to rely on something like a signed Java applet. Flash is restricted as Javascript and ActiveX controls will return "C:\fakepath".